# Contradiction to $2^n \ge c\cdot 6^\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, solution-verification, data-structure

I want to prove that the statement $2^n \in \Omega(6^\frac{n}{2})$ is not true.

Suppose in a way of contradiction that there exists a $c>0$, and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n>n_0$ we have $0 \le c\cdot 6^\frac{n}{2} \le 2^n$.

But for every $n>2c$ we have: $6^\frac{n}{2} > 6^c = (2^c)^{\log_26}=2^{c~log_26}>2^{2c}$.

But I do not know what to do with $c\cdot 6^\frac{n}{2}$...

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You're on the wrong track.  It won't help to say $6^{n/2}>2^{2c}$ because $2^{2c}$ is a constant.  I suggest you start by squaring both sides of $6^{n/2}c\leq2^n$

Comment: Maybe by doing log to both sides, we get that $\log_2c \le 0$, is that a contradiction?

Comment: For multiplication use `\cdot`, not `*`. The asterisk is reserved for operations such as convolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$2^n\ge c\cdot 6^{n/2}\Leftrightarrow (2/3)^{n/2}\ge c.$$

See that $2/3<1$. So $(2/3)^{n/2}$ decreases and goes to zero, when $n$ increases.

Comment: So taking $n>\log_2(\frac{2}{3})c$ ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your notation. For a fixed positive value of $c$, you should take $n>2\log_{2/3}c$.

Comment: Ohh I figured it out I think - by taking $n \ge \max(n_0,2 \log_{\frac{2}{3}}c)$ we get a contradiction, is that correct?

Comment: @TheCalc, I think it is simpler than that. Actually you could choose $n_0$ as the next integer number greater than $2\log_{2/3}c$. It means, you can choose $n_0=\lceil 2\log_{2/3}c \rceil$. So, you have the contradition for any $n>n_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate that!

Comment: i don't understand how to get a contradiction. by choosing  n0=⌈2log2/3c⌉  the equation $2^n \ge c\cdot 6^\frac{n}{2}$ is correct.